# Fill a table with content and avoid empty table

Tags: mysql, sql

i'm filling a table with new content like this:

```
TRUNCATE table1
foreach()
{
 INSERT ...
}
```

This means the table is empty for a few seconds and it takes 1-2 minutes to finish the inserts.

What is a better way?

- create table2
- inserting...
- delete table1
- rename table2 to table1

And maybe work with locking?

Thanks!

Comment: "better way".  That depends entirely on what you are doing.  Your question as written is just asking for an opinion.

Comment: Insert new data and then delete old data.

Answer (score 0):

Load data always take time, so, what your need?

If you need be fast and the table has to be avaliable, but you queryplan will be lost

Create a new table, load and rename.

If you can be slow just insert and delete the old data, but this will disorganize your table